# Unicode not converted when displayed

Tags: iphone, unicode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm localizing an app to spanish, and characters are encoded in the Localizable.strings file for that language using Unicode. For example, I have the entry:

```
"login.saveSettings"="Guardar configuraci\\u00F3n:";
```

which is displayed in a UILabel exactly like that ("Guardar configuraci\\u00F3n:"), instead of "Guardar configuración:". I tried different variations, such as "\u00F3", or "\\U00F3", but without any success.

I use NSLocalizedString this way:

```
self.saveSettingsLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"login.saveSettings", @"Save Settings:");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!
Mihai

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The correct variant is `\U00F3` with 1 backslash and a capital U.

Comment: Absolutely right. From all combinations I tried, I missed the right one. Thank you!

Comment: but if i am sending this one in JSON then its raising error invalid JSON escape sequence. but works fine if there is \u. but iOS is converting it only in \U

Comment: @Mrug: JSON and plist are two entirely different format!

Comment: Yes KennyTM i know. But the issue is not of plist. I am sending Unicodes to Webservice of JAVA but it is firing error just because of Capital U in unicode. JAVA guy is asking me to send it in small casing . Then What to do ?